# How to remove GraphQL from Magento 2.3?

Tags: module, magento2.3, uninstall, open-graph, graphql

I'm not planning to use GraphQL in my Magento 2.3 and I would like to remove it at all for now, not just disable it.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to remove it from your Magento 2.3 installing this package below:

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-graphql:2.3.1
```

OR

You could specify the packages to be removed in your **composer.json**, as you can see below.

```
"replace": {
    "magento/module-authorizenet-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-braintree-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-checkout-agreements-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-related-product-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-paypal-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-bundle-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-cms-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-configurable-product-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-customer-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-directory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-eav-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-theme-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-quote-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-send-friend-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-swatches-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-graph-ql": "*"
  },
```

Comment: Just to extend this answer a lot of stuff can be removed from vanilla install https://www.integer-net.com/make-magento-2-small-again/

Answer (score 0):

we can disable graphQL modules using below command

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AuthorizenetGraphQl Magento_BraintreeGraphQl Magento_BundleGraphQl Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl Magento_DirectoryGraphQl Magento_GraphQlCache Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl Magento_PaypalGraphQl Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl Magento_SalesGraphQl Magento_SendFriendGraphQl Magento_StoreGraphQl Magento_SwatchesGraphQl Magento_TaxGraphQl Magento_ThemeGraphQl Magento_VaultGraphQl Magento_WeeeGraphQl Magento_WishlistGraphQl
```